# how to make Oracke & SQL Database connection with WCF

Tags: .net, oracle

I am developing WCF service, and I want to make a database connection with oracle and sql in service. Please tell me how will do this.

Comment: @Aman... You've asked 8 questions, and not one marked as an answer??

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do that.

I'd highly suggest checking out LINQ-to-Entities.

- TUTORIAL: http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-started-with-Linq-To-Entities.aspx

There is also LINQ-to-SQL

- Blah... I'm not going to link to a tutorial because LINQ-to-Entities is better IMO.

Or, of course, the old-school method, using OracleClient:

- DOCS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx
- SAMPLE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.80%29.aspx